# Spring WebFlow Cannot Handle Multiple iframes

Tags: jquery, spring, jsf, spring-webflow

my problem is almost identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602523/when-i-add-a-url-to-a-list-and-then-using-ajax-i-try-to-show-the-lists-conten) unanswered(the answer is not accepted) question.
the problem is when i add multiple iframes to one xhtml file (which is managed by webflow) after a certain number (in my case the number is 5) the page drop all the ajax calls and refreshes itself.

the point is when the content of iframe is also webflow managed xhtml files this problem happens but if i change it to an external link like stackoverflow.com the peocess of adding iframes works like a charm and i can add any number of iframes that i want.

so, do you know what the problem might be? is there any suggested workaround like using different dispatcher along side with webflow?